# JQuery tab and JScrollPane combination is not working properly

Tags: jquery

I'm using a jQuery tab and inside the I've used a jScroll Pane, tab code is below

```
$(function(){$('.tabs').each(function(){var currentTab, ul=$(this);$(this).find('a').each(function(i){

var a=$(this).bind('click',

    function(){
        if(currentTab){

            ul.find('a.active').removeClass('active');

            $(currentTab).hide();

        }

        currentTab=$(this).addClass('active').attr('href');

        $(currentTab).show().jScrollPane();

        return false;

    }

);

$(a.attr('href')).hide();});});});</script>
```

but initially my first tab is not showing, but the first tab should show initially. **Can any body solve this?**